# CSS expand element vertically and move pseudo element

Tags: css, ribbon, pseudo-element

On a website I am creating I have a navigational bar across the top of the page which I want to expand/animate vertically when hovered on. I am also using the *:after* pseudo element to create a ribbon effect. The problem is that I can't seem to make the "Ribbon part" move down when the menu item is hovered over. I have played about with it for a while now and I know it's something simple but I just can't figure it out.

I have the code on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/FTf4pBEi

Answer (score 0):

I increased the hover height and the ribbon seems to work. I'm not sure exactly what you're after since there are no submenu items.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kts5y/3/

```
.menu_item:hover {
  height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific, I wanted the .menu_item:after to move down along with the .menu_item so it still retains the ribbon shape

Comment: I see now that you had stated that. I'll see if I can find some time to take another crack at it.